# Is it possible to use search result as part of $args?

Tags: wordpress

I like to show extra information on search result page.  Information like some kind of caculation using meta value.

First of all, I set $args for extra information separately from serach result.

```
<?php
$name= get_search_query();
$args_sold = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type'   => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'category__not_in' => array( 3, 137 ),
'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'and',
                                array(
                                'relation' => 'or',
                                                array( 
                                                'key'=> 'species1',
                                                'value' => $name,
                                                'compare' => '=',
                                                ),

                                                array( 
                                                'key'=> 'species2',
                                                'value' => $name,
                                                'compare' => '=',
                                                ),),             
                                array( 
                                'key'=> '1aa',
                                'compare' => 'EXIST',
                                ),                       
                    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args_sold);
$all_num_sold = $query->found_posts;
?>
```

This code itself works fine, but I found it does not work completely because the most searched words are not same as meta value that I registered.

Im thinking that I need to set search result itself as part of $args.  Is it possible to do it?

Comment: "the most searched words are not same as meta value that I registered" <-- can you explain a bit better...? Is the problem that it's displaying all posts?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My question was bad enough. Sorry about lacking of vocabularies. I think I wanted to change search string to array style.  Now I could solve it by  parse_str( $args, $args ).  Combine 2 $args.  Thank you for trying to help me anyway.  Have a good day!